Why was one question about Trinitarian hermeneutical approaches to the Hebrew bible closed but another left open?
Recently https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/96567/revisions - "How do Trinitarians distinguish whether the Hebrew bible is referring to the "being" or "person[s]" of God in the verses that declare oneness?" was closed and moved to another site. However this nearly identical question How do Trinitarians distinguish which person the Bible is referring to throughout the scriptures when the three titles of the Godhead is not used? has been allowed to stay open.
What is the difference between the two? Why would the first question, which asks how a specific hermeneutical approach answers questions about a handful of verses, be off topic for Hermeneutics? Is that question not hermeneutical enough for the Hermeneutics stack exchange?

It's a judgement call, without an answer that will satisfy everyone, but when I saw them, I saw one question with multiple verses and one question with one verse.
If you think it should be closed, feel free to vote to close it. You could also write a comment explaining why you think so.
Note however that because the question asker is currently suspended on Christianity.SE it cannot be migrated, only closed.

It seems that twelve users all support you as they have up-voted the question.
